# how to center widgets in a row?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have my TopNavBarLogo with the text "BestFitnesstrackerEU" on the left (start of the row), my TopNavBarItems "Informationen" and "Neuigkeiten" in the middle and at the end of the row "Login" and "Teilnehmer werden".

My problem is, that I can't center my TopNavBarItems in the middle. I tried to create a new row and use "mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center" and "mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min" to center it, but without success.

At the moment I am using "SizedBox(width: screenSize.width / 5)," to center the widgets, but there need to be a more accurate methode for this.

Here an image how the TopNavigationBar looks like:

[image]

How can I center the TopNavBarItems "Informationen" and "Neuigkeiten"?

**Edit:**

Renik Shiroya:

```
mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center
```

if you use min option, then please change to below:

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max
```

answer: even when I use "mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max" it won't change anything.

This is an image when I delete my "SizedBox(width: screenSize.width / 5)," and use "mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max":
[image]

**code:**

```
  import 'package:bestfitnesstrackereu/widgets/top_navigation_bar/top_navigation_bar_logo.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '../../routing/route_names.dart';
    import '../top_navbar_item/top_navbar_item.dart';
    
    
    class TopNavigationBarTabletDesktop extends StatelessWidget {
      const TopNavigationBarTabletDesktop({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Container(
          height: 100,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 30,),
              TopNavBarLogo(),
              SizedBox(width: 30,),
              Visibility(child: Text( "BestFitnesstrackerEU", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,))),
    
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget> [
                  SizedBox(width: screenSize.width / 5),
                  TopNavBarItem('Informationen', HomeRoute),
                  SizedBox(width: 40,),
                  TopNavBarItem('Neuigkeiten', EpisodesRoute),
                  SizedBox(width: 40,),
                ],
              ),
    
              Spacer(),
              SizedBox(width: 40,),
              TopNavBarItem('Login', AuthenticationPageRoute),
              SizedBox(width: 40,),
              TopNavBarItem('Teilehmer werden', RegristrationRoute)     
              SizedBox(width: 40,),
    
      ],
          ),
            );
      }
}
```

Thank you a lot for ur help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the row and used a spacer() instead.

Dunno why I haven't done this before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

if you use min option, then please change to below :

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want three widget in row (Left (Starting), center and right (ending)) you can use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to Row. No need to give calculated space between 2 widgets.